# SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word "await"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I keep getting this error even thought I am in a asynchronous function...

```
import { dirname, join } from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

export async function importer(client) {
    const dir = join(__dirname, "../../commands/")

    const commandCategories = readdirSync(dir)
    for (let cat of commandCategories) {
        const commandFiles = readdirSync(join(dir, cat)).filter(files => files.endsWith(".js"));

        for (const file of commandFiles) {
            const command = await import(join(dir, cat, file));
            client.commands.set(command.default.name, command.default);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something I am missing? I definitely need the await part in `import` in `const command`. It imports a few commands then it drops the mentioned error in title on the console output.

Thanks.

Comment: For me this code doesn't have any syntax errors...

Comment: I might be wrong and I can't check now, but I don't think you can await and assign to a constant.

Comment: @Aioros You can! Otherwise it wouldn't be very useful, if you couldn't use its return value...

Comment: I am not sure why it happens either, when it drops the error, commands stop importing, leaving only 6-7 commands out of the 25+ commands imported...

Comment: Did you check the full stack? My assumption is that the syntax error is actually in a module you import, not on the import expression itself! So trying to import that bad module fails with the syntax error because that error was raised while parsing the module. (You could also try logging the filename before importing the file so you know which one caused the error.)

Comment: ```SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:117:18)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:361:14)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:70:21)```

This is the error. As soon as I remove the `await` off the `import`, the error goes away. I can send my function manager if needed.

Comment: The error doesn't "go away" but you just no longer see it because you ignore the rejected promise you get from `import`.

Comment: I see the person with the issue is running v13.9.0 Node, I am running v17.9.0.

Comment: @nikoszz Yet, the issue is still open in GitHub, so nothing changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem isn't the `importer` code, it's in one of the modules you attempted to import (and `import` crashes on parsing it)!

It's a [bug in node](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/32177) that such a non-helpful error is thrown when this syntax error is encountered during *dynamic* `import`.

Try logging the filenames before importing them so you can see at which file it crashes. Once you know which file failed to parse, do a *static* import of it for testing, so you can get a proper error that tells you which line has the issue.